# Convert data/value list to object properties

Tags: powershell

I have an array of nested dictionary-style arrays, like `$Events` here, with a column of property names and a column of values:

```
PS > $Events[0].EventProperties

Name      #text
-------   -------
EventName ItBroke
Category  Bad
When      2020
```

For reference, the data like this that I use is usually from xml that looks like this, so maybe I could process this better?:

```
<Events>
  <EventProperties Name="EventName">ItBroke</EventProperties>
  <EventProperties Name="Category">Bad</EventProperties>
  <EventProperties Name="When">2020</EventProperties>
</Events>
<Events ... />
```

I want to convert the nested `EventProperties` member arrays to objects instead, with properties of Name =`Name` and Value =`#text` like below:

```
PS > $EventData[0]

EventName : ItBroke
Category  : Bad
When      : 2020
```

I'll answer with the way I do this currently, but it's just slow and scales poorly so I'm looking for help structuring this better. It feels like something simple that I don't know the correct terms for to find on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can optimize what you have already done by using hash tables to store property/value data, converting those hash tables into custom objects, and then avoiding the use of the inefficient `+=` to expand an array.

```
$EventData = $Events | Foreach-Object {
    $hash = [ordered]@{}
    $_.EventProperties | Foreach-Object {
        $hash[$_.Name] = $_.innertext
    }
    [pscustomobject]$hash
}
$EventData
```

You could potentially look at PowerShell 7 and consider `Foreach-Object -Parallel` if you have a lot of `EventProperties` nodes.

All of the looping is required because you want to convert attribute names to properties. The `[xml]` accelerator converts element (node) names to properties. I believe this behavior is typical for the other XML deserializers in PowerShell.

---

If you restructured your XML to have those attribute names be element names instead, only the conversion from XML to objects would be required:

```
# sample x.xml
<root>
<Events>
  <EventProperties>
    <EventName>ItBroke</EventName>
    <Category>Bad</Category>
    <When>2020</When>
  </EventProperties>
</Events>
<Events>
  <EventProperties>
    <EventName>ItBroke</EventName>
    <Category>Bad</Category>
    <When>2020</When>
  </EventProperties>
</Events>
</root>

# Conversion Code
$x = [xml](Get-Content x.xml)
$x.Root.Events.EventProperties

# Output
EventName Category When
--------- -------- ----
ItBroke   Bad      2020
ItBroke   Bad      2020
```

Comment: Awesome, the construction using `$hashtable[$newPropertyName]` and the conversion to `[pscustomobject]` were both new to me, and work great! I do wish the data was formatted better, but sometimes it's not... This will be helpful for those times :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this is by individually creating objects, then adding member properties from the data to the object via a double `ForEach` loop

```
$EventData=@()                           # Create empty list object
# Iterate through events
Foreach ($event in $Events) {            # Iterate through events
    $object = New-Object PSObject        # Create new object for event data
    $event.EventProperties | Foreach {   # Iterate through data, and create new member properties
        Add-Member -InputObject $object `
            -MemberType NoteProperty `
            -name $_.Name `
            -Value $_.'#text'
    }
    $EventData += $object                # Add new object to result list
}
$EventData                               # Output result, matches example from question
```

This is **slow**, but dynamic enough to not have to worry about how many properties / whether all properties exist per event.